# Hiding a severely dished bedroom floor

Tags: hardwood-floor, self-leveling-concrete

I have a bedroom with a hardwood floor that is severely out of level. I would say is is 1.5 inches out of level over 6 feet, with the lowest spot in the center of the room. I do eventually want to fix this issue, but it will be challenging due to the fact there is no subfloor (3/4 T&G is nailed directly to joists). For now, I am looking for a temporary solution. I want to lay down a circular rug in the room, but I need to support it in the middle to hide the sag. My kinda crazy idea was to lay down 6mil plastic, pour self leveler on top of the plastic, and then lay the rug on top after it cures. This should make the floor more level, while also allowing the floor and leveler to move independently. Any thoughts on this? I also thought about building up cork roll or something similar underneath the rug, but I thought this might feel too squishy when walking over it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Adding that amount of concrete (mass) will likely make the floor curve more.

Comment: I would find out why the floor dips that much first.  Adding more weight on top of a few broken joists will not lead to happiness.   An inch and a half dip in the centre of a room is not a good structural sign.  Fix before hiding.

Comment: The underlying issue has been previously fixed to some degree using steel plates bolted to the sagging joist. Leveling the underlying structure is not really possible for me at the moment since there's a bedroom and bathroom on top.

Comment: I think the hint here is that a 1.5" dip across 6' indicates a _severe_ structural issue and that hiding it for a couple of months will lead to hiding it for a couple of... oops, it just collapsed. Nobody likes to spend money on fixing inconvenient things like this, but it'll be cheaper to fix it now than it will be to rebuild while paying medical bills for anyone hospitalized when the floor finally lets go. Oh, and possibly dealing with lawsuits if others get injured, too.

Comment: What is below this bedroom? Is it the basement or a crawlspace or more finished living space?

Comment: As mentioned above, the floor joists have been sistered with steel plates, probably 30-40 years ago if I had to guess. Nobody is falling through the floor. This is on a second floor, with living space underneath.

Comment: When you fix it are you going to try and salvage the hardwood, or will that go away?

Comment: If I would to sister steel plates to sagging floor joists, think I might want the joists levelled, not leave an 1 1/2 inch dip.

Comment: On a 2nd floor I absolutely would not use self leveling compound, the amount this would cost you could purchase a Jack and start slowly raising the floor over a few months. Along with the weight the compound would ruin or make it just about impossible to fix later.

Comment: Honestly, if you're going to ostrich a major structural problem (the plates ***aren't*** working!), I don't really understand why you can't just ignore the symptoms as well.